# Gesture recognizer in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have this code in LongTapGestureRecognizer for autoscrolling a view:

```
-(void) longPressDetectedgesture:
        (UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    _btnautoscrollstop.hidden = NO;
    _btnautoscroll.hidden = YES;

    // if (autoscrollTimer == nil) { 

    autoscrollTimer = [NSTimer 
        scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(55.0/1000.0) 
        target:self 
        selector:@selector(autoscrollTimerFired:)  
        userInfo:nil  
        repeats:YES]; 
}
- (void)autoscrollTimerFired:(NSTimer*)timer { 
    CGPoint scrollPoint = self.table.contentOffset; 
    scrollPoint = CGPointMake(scrollPoint.x, scrollPoint.y + 1); 
    [self.table setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:NO]; 
}
```

It works perfect for me, but my need is, the autoscrooling must stop when the user taps the screen for Longgesture for the second time and vise versa. How to stop this, when the user taps for a second time.

Comment: @mvds i tried  lot to achive this,but no luck i put -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 NSUInteger numTaps = [[touches anyObject] tapCount];
 
  if(numTaps == 2) { inside this i put the deactivate time code but no luck

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're almost there. You probably want something like this:

```
if (recogniser.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    if (autoscrollTimer == nil) { 
        autoscrollTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(55.0/1000.0) 
                                                           target:self 
                                                         selector:@selector(autoscrollTimerFired:)  
                                                         userInfo:nil  
                                                          repeats:YES];
    } else {
        [autoscrollTimer invalidate];
        autoscrollTimer = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: i put your code ,but when i relese my finger it didnot scroll,auto scroling occur only when i tap the screen continusly,whhen i rel;ese it it stops

Comment: Edited. Just need to check what state it's in. You might want to tweak it to stop when the state changes to `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` or something though. I'm sure you can figure out how to do that.

Comment: Well what *exactly* do you want to do? And how are you creating the gesture recogniser? Doing something along the lines I suggest is definitely the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

What i usually do is declare a global BOOL Alter; and initialize it Alter = NO; in viewDidLoad (or any other method) then

```
-(void) longPressDetectedgesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    if(Alter)
    {
      Alter = NO;
      [autoscrollTimer inValidate];
    }
    else
    {
       Alter = YES;
       _btnautoscrollstop.hidden = NO;
       _btnautoscroll.hidden = YES;

     // if (autoscrollTimer == nil) { 

     autoscrollTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(55.0/1000.0) 
                                                   target:self 
                                               selector:@selector(autoscrollTimerFired:)  
                                                 userInfo:nil  
                                                  repeats:YES]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you do that and not just use if `autoscrollTimer` is `nil`, though? What does it gain you by having a random extra flag when you already have one in `autoscrollTimer`?

Comment: Because he might be setting the timer from somewhere else in addition to longPress detection?

Answer (score 0):

create a BOOL called shouldFireTimer in viewDidLoad or similar and update it's value each time you detect a longpress

```
-(void) longPressDetectedgesture: (UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    _btnautoscrollstop.hidden = NO;
    _btnautoscroll.hidden = YES;
    if ( shouldFireTimer ) {
        [autoscrollTimer invalidate];
        autoscrollTimer = nil;
    } else {
        autoscrollTimer = [NSTimer 
            scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(55.0/1000.0) 
            target:self 
            selector:@selector(autoscrollTimerFired:)  
            userInfo:nil  
            repeats:YES]; 
    }
    shouldFireTimer = !shouldFireTimer;
}

- (void)autoscrollTimerFired:(NSTimer*)timer { 
     CGPoint scrollPoint = self.table.contentOffset; 
     scrollPoint = CGPointMake(scrollPoint.x, scrollPoint.y + 1); 
     [self.table setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:NO]; 
}
```

or like Matt says above maybe just check nil status instead of using a BOOL. I suggest using a BOOL as you maybe firing autoscrollTimerFired in other circumstances too (from a button for example) i.e. it might not be nil when you want to call it.